# I am trying to generate Jmeter HTML report through Jenkins Pipeline where i am using linux command

Tags: html, linux, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to generate Jmeter HTML report through Jenkins where i am using linux command, But getting error.

Below Error:-

13:48:05  + jmeter -g /home//ubuntu//Performance_Pluggin//apache-jmeter-5.6.2//bin//15NetworkFeatures_SinglePT.jmx.csv /home//ubuntu//Performance_Pluggin//apache-jmeter-5.6.2//bin//NewLMCopy.jmx.csv -o dashboard
13:48:05  Error: Unknown option -g
13:48:05  Try 'jmeter --help' for more information.

When i will execute same command through window , It's working and generate the HTML report.

Comment: Possibly you are using a different JMeter version on your Jenkins server, which does not support the `-g` parameter yet, as the message says. Try `jmeter --version` on both sides to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JMeter from [Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) you're sitting on JMeter 2.13 which was released in 2015.

[HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) was **introduced in JMeter 3.0** so you need at least this version.

In general it's [recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so I think you need to [install the latest version of JMeter manually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) and it should resolve your issue.

like instead of `jmeter` use `/home/ubuntu/Performance_Pluggin/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin/./jmeter.sh`

Comment: After movind into the correct version still not able to generate the Dashboard through Linux machine ...Commands are displaying under the non GUI mode but its not working like in windows.

Example:-